# Проблемы с переводом в двоичный код java

Tags: binary, java

```
byte[] ip = new byte[]{(byte) 192, (byte) 168, 1, 1};
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((int)ip[0]));
```

Этот код выводит на экран следующее

> 11111111111111111111111111000000

А `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(192));`
Вот это

> 11000000

Почему так?

Answer (score 5):

У байта 127 макс значение. Как вы 192 туда собрались записать!? В дополнение:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-64));
```

Выведет:

> 11111111111111111111111111000000

Answer (score 2):

Потому что вы явно ожидаете беззнаковое преобразование (раз положили 192 в байт), а `(int)ip[0]` - плохой способ преобразования из byte в int.

Попробуйте так: `(ip[0] & 0xff)`