# Как вывести в консоль битовые представления чисел?

Tags: java

Допустим, у меня есть такой массив:

```
byte[] ip = new byte[] {(byte) 192, (byte) 168};
```

Я хочу получить строку из чисел в их битовом представлении, вида `11000000 10101000` и делаю метод `print`:

```
public static void print(byte[] bytes) {

}
```

Как мне сделать вывод в консоль в этом принте ?

Comment: Ищите в этом вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/332748/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-java
Мне не на чем проверить. Поэтому дальше сами.

Comment: @Kromster,  разве я не указал пример строки, которую хочу получить в "правильном выводе" ? Отличается тем, что в моем случае выводятся числа в десятеричном виде, а мне надо в двоичном.

Comment: Почти. Надо вывести на консоль битовое представление числа.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Уже есть готовый метод для Integer

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29

Если заморачиваться, то можно почитать как это реализовано в яве

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toBinaryString%28int%29

Вот так это будет выглядеть для byte:

```
public static String toBinaryString(byte i) {
    char digits[] = {'0', '1'};
    char[] buf = new char[8];
    int charPos = 8;
    byte radix = (byte)2;
    byte mask = (byte)(radix - 1);
    do {
    buf[--charPos] = digits[i & mask];
        i >>>= 1;
    } while (i != 0);
    return new String(buf, charPos, (8 - charPos));
}
```

Comment: “Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”

Answer (score 4):

Что-то вроде:

```
System.out.print((b & 0b10000000) != 0 ? 1 : 0);
System.out.print((b & 0b01000000) != 0 ? 1 : 0);
System.out.print((b & 0b00100000) != 0 ? 1 : 0);
.....
System.out.println();
```

Где b - ваш байт

Answer (score 1):

Не могу сказать о "правильности" этого метода, но он работает согласно вашим требованием.

```
public static void print(byte[] bytes) {

   for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) { 
      System.out.print(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString((bytes[i]) & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0') + " ");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант (похож на вариант Lysiakov Mykyta):

```
    public static void print(byte[] bytes) {    
        String currentBinary;
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            currentBinary = Integer.toBinaryString(256 + (int) b);
            System.out.print(currentBinary.substring(currentBinary.length() - 8) + " ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void binaryPrint (int q) {
        if(q == 0) System.out.print(0);
        else {
            int nlz = Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(q); 
            q <<= nlz;
            for(int p = 0; p < 32 - nlz; p++) {
                int n = (Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(q) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                System.out.print(n);        
                q <<= 1;
            }       
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```