# Вывод числа на консоль в бинарном виде

Tags: java

Хочу вывести число `192` (это частный случай, так у меня массив типа `byte`) в двоичном виде на консоль. Делаю так:

```
byte b = (byte) 192;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((int) b));
```

В результате получаю:

```
11111111111111111111111111000000
```

Это не совсем то, что я ожидал. Как мне получить мои `11000000`?

Comment: Сдвиг и проверка старшего бита не подошли?

Comment: Надо обрезать левые 24 символа

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести в консоль битовые представления чисел?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583301/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPD**. Автор кардинально поменял вопрос, поэтому ответ можно читать сразу с **UPD1**.

Например, так:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(192));
```

А зачем Вы преобразовываете `int` в `byte` – весьма непонятно.

PS. Метод `Integer.toBinaryString(...)` возвращает строку без лидирующих нулей. То есть при выполнении:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1));
```

Вы получите:

```
1
```

Если Вам нужны нули в начале строки, то можете сделать, например, так:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(1)).replace(' ', '0'));
```

**UPD 1**.

`byte` – 8-битовый тип (**со знаком**), область его значений `[-(2^8)/2;(2^8)/2 - 1]`, то есть `[-128;127]`.

Выполнение преобразования:

```
byte b = (byte) 192;
```

происходит следующим образом:

Так как `192` не помещается в `byte`, то вычисляется остаток от деления числа `192` на диапазон значений `byte`:

```
192 % 2^8 = 192
```

Так как остаток от деления все равно не влезает в `byte`, то происходит вычитание размера диапазона `byte` из остатка от деления, то есть из числа `192`:

```
192 - 256 = -64
```

И в итоге, в переменной `b` будет содержаться значение `-64`.

Comment: Поправил и уточнил вопрос. Мне нужно именно преобразовать тип `byte`.

Comment: @faoxis, Зачем Вы преобразовываете `int` в `byte`? Число `192` в `byte` не поместится.

Comment: Почему ? Оно же меньше 255.

Comment: @faoxis, `byte` – 8-битовый тип (со знаком), область его значений `[-(2^8)/2;(2^8)/2 - 1]`, то есть `[-128;127]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte b = (byte) 192;
int i = Byte.toUnsignedInt(b);
String str = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(segment)).replaceAll(" ", "0");
System.out.println(str);
```

Вывод:

```
11000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void binaryPrint (int q) {
        if(q == 0) System.out.print(0);
        else {
            int nlz = Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(q); 
            q <<= nlz;
            for(int p = 0; p < 32 - nlz; p++) {
                int n = (Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(q) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                System.out.print(n);        
                q <<= 1;
            }       
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```